# Second figure on page is covering text in the bottom of the paragraph above

Tags: spacing, graphics, bounding-box

I'm trying to create a page which will have three figures on it as well as some text. However in my output the top of the second figure is obscuring the bottom of the text above it. I've tried using `[H]`, `[!h]` and `[t]` but it doesn't alter it. The only thing that seems to work is placing `[b]` after the figure but that sticks it to the very bottom of the page which looks awful (plus I want to place a third figure there).

I've included the preamble in the code along with the relevant page.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.25cm}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}


\newpage


\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics{PreisachPeriodicp0.1full}
\caption{Full output for p=0.1}
\label{fig:fullp0.1}
\end{figure}

Figures X-Y show the output of this model over various different values for the parameter p. The blue line tracks the population fraction ($\mu$) of the phenotypes who operate under threshold 1. The red line is for threshold 2 and the green line for threshold 3. Figure \ref{fig:fullp0.1} shows the output over 100 time steps when p is equal to 0.1. It appears from this that all three sub-populations are tending toward periodic equilibrium. This can be seen more easily in figure YY which depicts a period of time much further into the future.


\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics{PreisachPeriodicp0.1}
\caption{End output for p=0.1}
\label{fig:p0.1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Here's how it turns out:

[image]

Comment: If you remove the paragraph text between the two figures, does the bottom image stick into the top one as well? If this is the case, then this could be a bounding box issue with your (second) image. You could consider using [`epstool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstool) to fix that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114429/second-figure-on-page-is-covering-text-in-the-bottom-of-the-paragraph-above?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it won't be allowed to cover a whole page with floats. Try experimenting with these:

- `\setcounter{topnumber}{n}`: maximum number of floats at the top of a page
- `\setcounter{bottomnumber}{n}`
- `\setcounter{totalnumber}{n}`
- `\renewcommand{\topfraction}{x}`: maximum fraction starting from top choose 1.0 here
- `\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{x}`
- `\renewcommand{\textfraction}{x}`: should be 0.0
- `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{x}`: mimimal fraction that has to be used before a new page for the next fraction is begun; use 1.0
- `\setlength{\floatsep}{m units}`: distance between floats
- `\setlength{\textfloatsep}{m units}`: distance between float and text

You could also choose small `\floatsep` and put lines above and below figures for distinction (these commands are usually empty, so *no* line):

- `\renewcommand{\topfigrule}{0.9\textwidth}`
- `\renewcommand{\botfigrule}{0.9\textwidth}`

Hope this helps, let me know how you did.

Comment: Hello Tom, I'm having the same issues. Where do I put these commands you suggested?

Comment: You would put them in your preamble, thus before `\begin{document}`